# Extract a row from a Python numpy array by condition

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have an array (called "attractors") which looks like this:

```
[['0000000000' '0.0' '0.0']
 ['0000000001' '0.0' '1.0']
 ['0000000010' '0.0' '2.0']
...........................
```

I want to create new array which contains all rows where the third column was 0 in the original array. I try the following:

```
print(attractors[attractors[: , 2] == 0][: , 0])
```

but I receive the following error:

```
            json export to visualize state transition diagram with compression
 - tests.py:247: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; 
    returning scalar instead, but in the 
        future will perform elementwise comparison 
              print(attractors[attractors[: , 2] == 0][: , 0])
```

If I put brackets on the condition, like this:

```
print(attractors[attractors[: , 2] == "0"][: , 0])
```

then the error does not appear, but the results is not what I expected (only empty brackets [])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isn't it because you have strings of format '0.0'

so maybe you should do something like this

```
print(attractors[attractors[: , 2] == '0.0'][: , 0])
```

Comment: It works great, but the outcome is an array with numbers inside. How can I make it to have outcome as an array with strings inside (i.e. in the same format as in the primary array)

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
[x for x in attractors if x[2] == 0]
```

If it's a string you can change the equality to `== '0.0'`